# blank Birt report view in java show error

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

i am new To Java so I have tried to connect MySql And show report in Birt it not working so i tried to make it empty report just to see the report still not working . it give this error .
 i am using eclipse 4.5 mars with the latest Birt release the Java SDK is 1.8

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.handleFatalExceptions(EngineTask.java:2380)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:277)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:86)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1325)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:158)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunReportActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunReportActionHandler.java:81)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageActionHandler.__checkDocumentExists(BirtGetPageActionHandler.java:58)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.prepareParameters(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:118)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:103)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:87)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
   at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
   at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
   at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(ServletManager.java:180)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl$LegacyServlet.service(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:1271)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:162)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:63)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.doDispatch(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:413)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.doDispatch(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:341)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.doDispatch(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:204)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:91)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:70)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:356)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mozilla/javascript/ScriptOrFnNode
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.(PreparedQuery.java:100)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:75)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:76)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQueryUtil.newInstance(PreparedQueryUtil.java:211)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataEngineImpl.prepare(DataEngineImpl.java:426)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.prepare(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:473)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.prepare(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:673)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.doPrepareQuery(AbstractDataEngine.java:226)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doPrepareQuery(DteDataEngine.java:272)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.prepare(AbstractDataEngine.java:182)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ReportExecutor.execute(ReportExecutor.java:122)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportExecutor.execute(WrappedReportExecutor.java:60)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.emitter.ReportEmitterExecutor.execute(ReportEmitterExecutor.java:71)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportExecutor.execute(WrappedReportExecutor.java:60)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplciateReportExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplciateReportExecutor.java:42)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportExecutor.execute(WrappedReportExecutor.java:60)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportExecutor.java:61)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ReportDocumentBuilder.build(ReportDocumentBuilder.java:234)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:269)
... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptOrFnNode cannot be found by org.eclipse.birt.data_4.4.2.v201501161327
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 81 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace is saying that [Mozilla Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Download_Rhino) is missing from your classpath, add it to your classpath.

Comment: I checked the source of Mozilla Rhino. It does not have any file called ScriptOrFnNode

Comment: Take a look at the version you are trying to import, I'm pretty sure that when I've posted the answer the problem was fixed with Rhino. I could even be in a transitive dependency of Rhino, try to add Rhino and its dependencies into the class path .

Comment: I tried 1.7.7 which did not have that file. Did you use a different version?